# Having multiple instances of a npm module

Tags: javascript, npm, handlebars.js

I'm currently implementing handlebars as a view engine. In order to serve different users with different helpers/partials I need multiple instances of Handlebars. Can anyone provide me an example of how to do this, because I can't figure out how to achieve this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`Handlebars.create()`](http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html):

> Creates an isolated Handlebars environment.
>
> ```
> var OtherHandlebars = Handlebars.create();
> ```
>
> Each environment has it's own helpers and
>   partials. This is only necessary for use cases that demand distinct
>   helpers or partials. Most use cases can use the root Handlebars
>   environment directly.
>
> Templates created for a given environment are
>   bound to that environment. This means that templates that need to run
>   in multiple environments will need to be recompiled or reconstructed
>   via Handlebars.template for each environment. This applies to partials
>   as well.